# detecting KEY_BACKSPACE in ncurses

Tags: ncurses, xterm

I am writing a ncurses program, and I need to detect `KEY_BACKSPACE`. I have test the program under 2 linux distros.

Under suse, it runs OK. But under archlinux, `KEY_BACKSPACE` is `263`, but what I print from program got `127`.

For suse, they're both `263`.

I am using `int ch = wgetch(somw_window)` to get the keypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends: whether <kbd>*Backspace*</kbd> sends ASCII BS (8) or ASCII DEL (127) is configurable with many terminal emulators, such as xterm.  The terminal description (selected by the `TERM` environment variable) has to be consistent with the terminal's configuration, otherwise curses will not see that the **`kbs`** capability (backspace-key) matches what your keyboard actually sends, and you'll just get the 8/127 value.

Some terminals send only one or the other (but most of the hard-coded ones which you'll encounter, use ASCII DEL).

Further reading (xterm FAQ):

- [Why doesn't my delete key work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erase)
- [Why did my delete key stop working?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_erased)
- [Well, how can I set my delete key?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_xmodmap)

Comment: Thomas, thank you very much ! I have 2 more questions. I am using putty&tmux, `TERM` is both `screen-256color`, and configuration under `putty-Terminal-Keyboard` are same. Is there anything more to config ? And from your post, `curses` is not responsible for this inconsistency ?

Comment: agree: curses is not responsible, it's usually a configurable thing.  One complicating thing with tmux is that it attempts to map the incoming characters to the terminal description, and may see for example a terminal description where `kbs=^H` where your terminal is actually `kbs=^?`.

Comment: how to check `^H`, `^?` difference in terminal? my putty config are both `^?`

Comment: Unless it's patched, the terminal database entry for screen-256color has `kbs=^H` -- that could be your problem.